# Can't Display the doubly linked list in C

Tags: c

Hello everyone I have made the program of doubly linked list and there are no errors but somehow when I insert and display the list then the list is empty ,following is my code for dispay and addatbeg function``

```
void addatbeg()// Ins`erting element in the beg
{
    struct dsnode*r,*q=p;
    if(p==NULL) //If the list is empty
    {
        //creating a new node
        p=(struct dsnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct dsnode));
        p->prev=NULL;
        p->data=item;
        p->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(q->next!=NULL)//Traverse the linked list till the last node is reached 
        {
            q=q->next;
        }

        //add a new node in the end
        r=(struct dsnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct dsnode));
        r->prev=q;
        r->data=item;
        r->next=NULL;
        q->next=r;
    }
}

void dis() //Display
{
    while(p!=0)
    {
        printf("%2d ",p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question: is it *printing* out the list at all? Or is it printing out the list and then the list is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, but if `p` is global then `dis()` displays *and empties* the list by modifying `p`.

Comment: empties by orphaning all elements

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Ben said: you would solve the emptying the list problem using a copy of `p`, like this:

```
struct dsnode *q = p;
while (q != 0)
{
    printf("%2d ", q->data);
    q = q->next;
}
```